# Whom does G-d pray to?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot

[Berakhot 7a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.7a.1?lang=bi) says:

> מִכָּאן שֶׁהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מִתְפַּלֵּל

Whom does G-d pray to?

Comment: The Ben Yehoyada says, "והלא לעצמו אומר כן"

Comment: @rosends, a short question deserves a short answer.

Comment: To Himself, obviously. But then by extrapolation, we should say that we pray to ourselves, which sounds odd. Unless this means we pray to access the universalism within ourselves, which doesn't.

Comment: Yosef, while this is a good question, you are treading dangerous waters here. This aggadic text obviously should not be taken literally. But your question implies that you are taking it literally, and if interpreted this way it will also pose a problem to our central belief system (especially the 13 ikarim).

Answer (score 5):

The next line on that page answers your question. G-d's prayer is to Himself, like it says:

> אָמַר רַב זוּטְרָא בַּר טוֹבִיָּה, אָמַר רַב: ״***יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנַי***
> שֶׁיִּכְבְּשׁוּ רַחֲמַי אֶת כַּעֲסִי, וְיִגּוֹלּוּ רַחֲמַי עַל
> מִדּוֹתַי, וְאֶתְנַהֵג עִם בָּנַי בְּמִדַּת רַחֲמִים, וְאֶכָּנֵס לָהֶם
> לִפְנִים מִשּׁוּרַת הַדִּין״.
>
> Rav Zutra bar Tovia said that Rav said:
> God says: ***May it be My will*** that My mercy will overcome My anger towards Israel for their transgressions,
> and may My mercy prevail over My other attributes through which Israel is punished,
> and may I conduct myself toward My children, Israel, with the attribute of mercy,
> and may I enter before them beyond the letter of the law.

Comment: Which word in the Talmud means “my will”?

Comment: I don’t see the word רצוני in the link in the question, nor in my edition of the Talmud.

Comment: @Alex Pardon me, the Hebrew phrase is, "יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנַי". The expression, " רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנַי" in this case is actually making the petition to G-d's innermost essence. Without getting into a long discussion which is at best tangential to the actual question, this is G-d above all aspects of differentiation meaning absolute Oneness. This also relates to teachings discussing kavannot for Birkat Kohanim if you are looking for related information.

Comment: "יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנַי" - lit. May it be the will from before me, which basically means: "May it be **my will**"